# Query string lost when div reload

Tags: jquery, html, jstl

A quick question that I'm having an issue with:

I have a `div` that loads another page which reads the query string parameter `id`.  On first load it works fine but for some reason when I reload the `div` when updates are made with:

```
$('#div').load('page.jsp');
```

It no longer reads the query string, thus it's not able to load the data from the database query. On the second page I'm just using `jstl` to read the param.id field. Any reason why this is happening? This works fine if I use session variables, but I'm trying to avoid using session variables.

What is the easiest way to grab the query string again on reload?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this works:

```
 $("#div").load("page.jsp?", {id: ${param.id}});
```